# Upgrade SDK Version in Google DataFlow - Java task via Jar file

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-composer

We recently upgraded a somewhat out of date Airflow instance in Google Cloud.
This caused our job to stop working.

The error in the log is:

> message: ""PullImage from image service failed" err="rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: manifest for gcr.io/cloud-dataflow/v1beta3/beam-java17-batch:2.34.0 not found: manifest unknown: Failed to fetch "2.34.0" from request "/v2/cloud-dataflow/v1beta3/beam-java17-batch/manifests/2.34.0"." image="gcr.io/cloud-dataflow/v1beta3/beam-java17-batch:2.34.0""

Having researched that error, I determined that this was caused by the fact that our version of Java on the server had been updated to version 17, and API Version 2.34.0 doesn't support the newer version.

I have attempted to follow the steps here: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/installing-beam-sdk?cloudshell=false#java

But I cannot find a pom.xml file anywhere in the cloud storage for the composer instance, or any reference to API version in the jar file that this job uses.